# How can print json object and array value in angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays, json

My app.js look like

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.eventmetrics = [
                        { 
                          _id: '57d439cf666a8d1080003e90',
                           firstName: [ 'name', 'text' ],
                           lastName: [ 'last', 'text' ],
                           taginvitations: ['first,second,third', 'text'],
                           userId: 1,
                           tagcontact: ['file,second,third,fourth', 'text'] 
                         }
                     ]
     });
```

i want print array of tag1 and tag2 in list  example

**invitations**

- first
- second
- thrid

**contact**

- first
- second
- thrid
- fourth

Comment: Where do you want to print?

Comment: my json is come from database and i want print dynamically  instead of  using static tag1 and tag2

Comment: Then assign tag1 to be whatever your server returns

Comment: can anyone give solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the contents of the array `tag1: ['first, second, third', 'text']`, `tag1` contains only two elements, then you must separate the content of the first element to obtain a new matrix that you need to present.

Use: `tag1[0].split(',')`.

This demo works with more than one element in the matrix `eventmetrics`.

Something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.eventmetrics = [{
    _id: '57d439cf666a8d1080003e90',
    firstName: ['name', 'text'],
    lastName: ['last', 'text'],
    tag1: ['first,second,third', 'text'],
    userId: 1,
    tag2: ['file,second,third,fourth', 'text']
  }, {
    _id: '87d439cf666a8d1080003e55',
    firstName: ['name', 'text'],
    lastName: ['last', 'text'],
    tag1: ['first,second,third', 'text'],
    userId: 1,
    tag2: ['file,second,third,fourth, fifth', 'text']
  }]
});
```

```css
#metrics {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div id="metrics" ng-repeat="em in eventmetrics">
      <h3 ng-bind="('_id: ' + em._id)"></h3>

      <div>
        <h4>tag1</h4>

        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="tag1 in em.tag1[0].split(',')" ng-bind="tag1"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>tag2</h4>

        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="tag2 in em.tag2[0].split(',')" ng-bind="tag2"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but my json is come from database and i want print dynamic instead of  using static tag1 and tag2

Comment: @Danny Fardy Jhonston Very nice example. It works for me.

Comment: This is my plunker link  and i mention the problem  in comment of  html file ...so please refer it ......https://plnkr.co/edit/Trc1EP4A9ei9qM7YYWyB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `eventmetrics` is always have length == 0, you can something like this using `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="text in eventmetrics[0].tag1"> {{ text }} </li>
</ul>


<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="text in eventmetrics[0].tag2"> {{ text }} </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the complete code in Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3TLG27?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <ul ng-repeat="y in eventmetrics">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in y" ng-show="key=='contact'||key=='invitation'">
    <b>{{key}}</b>
     <li ng-repeat="x in value[0].split(',')">
      {{x}}  
     </li>
    </div>
   </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

//script.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.eventmetrics = [
                    { 
                      _id: '57d439cf666a8d1080003e90',
                       firstName: [ 'name', 'text' ],
                       lastName: [ 'last', 'text' ],
                       invitation : ['first,second,third', 'text'],
                       userId: 1,
                       contact: ['file,second,third,fourth', 'text'] 
                     }
                 ];
    });
```

Comment: but my json is come from database and i want print dynamic instead of  using static tag1 and tag2

Comment: Refer my same plunker again. If this is what you are looking for.

Comment: ya it is work but still it is static...please go again my question because i did edit now ...and thank you for previous suggestion.

Comment: This is work if I put namespace as a **tag** before the contact and invitation but at a view side i also want print the invitation and contact so what can i do?

Comment: Check the code in plnkr, it prints contact and invitation as well.

Comment: Refer my plunker once again.....i ensure that you will solve it https://plnkr.co/edit/Trc1EP4A9ei9qM7YYWyB?p=preview

Comment: please refer my plunker .....i know only you give me the solution for my problem https://plnkr.co/edit/Trc1EP4A9ei9qM7YYWyB?p=preview